# How to use the STM32CUBE HAL library for a coninuouse i2c read

Tags: i2c, stm32f4discovery, hal

i am using the actual HAL library to read from and write to an AD7998 analog to digital converter with a stm32f407 discovery board. 
If I want to read several register values from the conversion result register, the manual says that the SCL and SDA signal should be maintained and I must not send a stop bit.
[AD7998 signal pattern to read several register values of one register](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhqYk.png).

I have tried to use Mem_Read. That seems to work for one 2 bytes register. But now i am not sure how to access the other parts of the conversion result registers to read more than the first channel.
If necessary, you can find the manual here -> [AD7998 manual](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD7997_7998.pdf), and my code below.

I tried to increase the number of bytes to read, but then the value of the first channel is written to the other bytes.
Has anybody of you tried this before?

```
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include "i2c.h"
#include "i2s.h"
#include "tim.h"
#include "usb_device.h"
#include "gpio.h"

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
uint16_t DeviceAdress= 0x20 << 1;
/* USER CODE END PV */

int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */
  HAL_StatusTypeDef stat = 0;
  uint8_t adcTxBuffer[16];
  uint8_t adcRxBuffer[16];
  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_I2C1_Init();
  MX_I2S3_Init();
  MX_SPI1_Init();
  MX_USB_DEVICE_Init();
  MX_TIM14_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  adcTxBuffer[0] = 0x00;
  adcTxBuffer[1] = 0xF8;                                                          // setup 4 channels (0, 1, 2, 3)
  stat = HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c1, DeviceAdress, 0x02, 2, adcTxBuffer, 2, 100);   //access the configuration register
  stat = HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1, DeviceAdress, 0x02, 2, adcRxBuffer, 2, 100);    // read vlaue from Configuration Register 
 HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA, 1);                                                   // start up adc
  HAL_Delay(1);                                                                  // delay for adc power up
  HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA, 1);                                                  // delay for sampling complete
  HAL_Delay(1);                                                                  // delay for sampling complete

  stat = HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1, DeviceAdress, 0x00, 2, adcRxBuffer, 16, 100);  // read conversion result register

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {

    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_PeriphCLKInitTypeDef PeriphClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage 
  */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 8;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 336;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 7;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV4;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_5) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  PeriphClkInitStruct.PeriphClockSelection = RCC_PERIPHCLK_I2S;
  PeriphClkInitStruct.PLLI2S.PLLI2SN = 192;
  PeriphClkInitStruct.PLLI2S.PLLI2SR = 2;
  if (HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&PeriphClkInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */

  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{ 
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     tex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */

/************************ (C) COPYRIGHT STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an alternative way to read the data, by configuring my register in each iteration. Works fine now.